# jquery ie7 problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

hi
my knowledge of javascript and jquery is pretty basic, so i have know idea what the cause the problem is.

i have created a simple slider to display two messages so one displays and the slides over to display the second one but it is not working in ie7, i have tried the code in ie8, chrome, firefox and opera and it works.

here is my code:

html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
            <div class="slides">
                <ul>
                    <li id="slide-one">
                        <h3>slider 1</h3>
                        <p>content goes here
                        <br/><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li id="slide-two">
                        <h3>slider 2</h3>
                        <p>content goes here
                        <br/><a href="#">click here</a></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="# "id="designer"></a>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#slideshow {
display: block;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
width: 520px;
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
color: black;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
font-family: Helvetica;
clear: both;
}

#slideshow h3 {
color: #aa102c;
}


.slides {    
height: 100px;
width: 520px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
float: right;
}

#slide-one {
width: 515px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 5px;
}

#slide-two {
width: 515px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 5px;
}

#slideshow .slides h3 {
margin-top: 0;}
```

js:

```
$slideshow = {
    context: false,
    tabs: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    slideSpeed: 2000,
    tabSpeed: 300,
    fx: 'scrollLeft',

    init: function() {

        this.context = $('#slideshow');

        this.tabs = $('ul.slides-nav li', this.context);


        this.prepareSlideshow();
    },

    prepareSlideshow: function() {

        $('div.slides > ul', $slideshow.context).cycle({
            fx: $slideshow.fx,
            timeout: $slideshow.timeout,
            speed: $slideshow.slideSpeed,
            fastOnEvent: $slideshow.tabSpeed,
            pager: $('ul.slides-nav', $slideshow.context),
            pagerAnchorBuilder: $slideshow.prepareTabs,
            before: $slideshow.activateTab,
            pauseOnPagerHover: true,
            pause: true
        });            
    },

    activateTab: function(currentSlide, nextSlide) {

        var activeTab = $('a[href="#' + nextSlide.id + '"]', $slideshow.context);

    }            
};


$(function() {

    $('body').addClass('js');

    $slideshow.init();
});
```

Comment: what javascript error, if any, is given?

Comment: have been fiddling with the css have have worked out that ie7 is not loading the javascript and is just displaying the text with the second slide hidden underneath the first out side to the size that i have set on the div tag

Comment: It is a seriously old jQuery. 1.6.1 is the current version

Comment: thanks for letting me know, have have changed it to version 1.6.1 but its still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here in IE7

Works in Fx4 on Mac and IE8 on Windows. Sorry I do not have IE7

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zHuqj/

Comment: The only reason I see this not working in IE7 is because of a script error on the fiddle site... if you have error display disabled it may be causing the issue and not the code in question.  (In other words, it works for me in IE7... do you have any extensions installed that may be causing it?)

Comment: my install of ie7 seems to be the problem then. i tried it on another computer and it works problem solved